# ViGEmBus Mouse2Joystick I can't attack

Tags: nintendo

I've installed ViGEmBus Mouse2Joystick to play my legaly adquired Nintendo game The Legend of Zelda BOTW and set up correctly all my actions BUT I cannot attack and I can't see why.
Here my parameters:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxNpP.png)